# Equivalent definitions in $\mathbb{R}$ topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

this might be trivial to you but I need to verify that $(i) \implies (ii)$ of these alternative statement of a Open Set (they are equivalent):

$(i)$ If all convergent sequence $(y_n)$ s.t. $y_n \in A^{c}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y_i \neq y_j \forall i\neq j$, then we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n \notin A$

$(ii)$ If for all $a \in A$ and all $(x_n)$ real sequence s.t. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n=a$, then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{x_n \colon n \geq n_0\} \subseteq A$

$(i) \implies (ii)$

If all convergent sequence $(y_n)$ s.t. $y_n \in A^{c}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y_i \neq y_j \forall i\neq j$, we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n \notin A$, then for all $a \in A$ and all $(x_n)$ real sequence s.t. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n=a$, exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{x_n \colon n \geq n_0\} \subseteq A$

Do you have any advice into how to prove that? I tried directly but it was not so easy. Should I try using contrapositive statement? Thank you.

Comment: So, we are talking about open subsets of $\Bbb R$, right?! And with respect to the usual topology, right?!

Comment: Yes, since it is the begining of topology, the question is about its simplest form. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketches:

(i) $\implies$ (ii): Let $x_n \to a$ where $a \in A$. If there does not exist $n_0$ such that $\{x_n : n \ge n_0\} \subseteq A$, then that means the sequence $(x_n)$ steps outside of $A$ infinitely often. So, there exists a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that lies outside of $A$, but converges to $A$. This contradicts (i).

(ii) $\implies$ (i): Let $y_n \to b$ where $y_n \notin A$ for all $n$. If $b \in A$, then (ii) implies $y_n \in A$ for all sufficiently large $n$, which is a contradiction.